# Pass a property of a class as a parameter?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I need to pass in a property of a class which is used twice in an extension method, to check for duplicate values in this property.

```
public static class MatchedProductsExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool IdenticalValues(this List<Product> matchedProducts)
    {
        var itemToMatch = matchedProducts.First();
        if (matchedProducts.All(p => p.PROPERTYTHATCANCHANGE == itemToMatch.PROPERTYTHATCANCHANGE))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

So I need to be able to pass in the name of a property of the `Product` class and then that replaces `PROPERTYTHATCANCHANGE`. For example, the properties in the `Product` class could be `ProdName` or `ProdUsers` and then I would need to check to see if there are items in the `matchedProducts` list which have the same values for these properties.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To pass in a string property name you're going to have to use reflection, which is not compile-time safe and is relatively slow. A more type-safe way would be to pass in a *delegate* instead of a property name:

```
public static bool IdenticalValues<T>(this List<Product> matchedProducts, Func<Product, T> matchExpression)
{
    var itemToMatch = matchedProducts.First();
    if (matchedProducts.All(p => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(matchExpression(p), matchExpression(itemToMatch))))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
bool allMatch = collection.IdenticalValues(i => i.PROPERTYTHATCANCHANGE );
```

You could even make it *completely* generic:

```
public static bool IdenticalValues<TEntity, TProperty>(this IEnumerable<TEntity> matchedEntities, Func<TEntity, TProperty> matchExpression)
{
    var itemToMatch = matchedEntities.First();
    if (matchedEntities.All(p => EqualityComparer<TProperty>.Default.Equals(matchExpression(p), matchExpression(itemToMatch))))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type <TProperty> and <TProperty>.

Comment: Technically you aren't passing an *expression* (that is an `Expression<>`) but a getter delegate

Comment: @DannyGoodall Check my edit - I used the default comparer instead of the `==` operator.

Comment: @xanatos I meant `expression` in the conceptual sense, not a literal `Expression` object.  I changed it to avoid confusion, though.

Comment: @DStanley Thank you :) I figured out that I no longer receive an error if I stick a .ToString() on the end although I don't think that is the best way of going about things.

Comment: @DannyGoodall No, do NOT compare by calling `ToString`.  There are WAY too many ways that two instances could generate the same string but have different values.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest doing this in a type-safe way:

```
public static bool IdenticalValues<T>(this List<Product> matchedProducts, Func<Product, T> selector)
{
    var itemToMatch = matchedProducts.First();
    if (matchedProducts.All(p => selector(p) == selector(p)))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

and then calling it like

```
matchesProducts.IdenticalValues(p => p.SomeProperty)
```